# How to check if the checkbox has been selected more than 3?

Tags: jquery, session

So far as i know, the checkbox can be detect as a boolean right. However i need to make condition if more than 3, then it will do something. For now i just make it alert to know if the condition met. Can anyone help?

```
$(document).delegate('.sBorrow', 'change', function(){
            var sBorrowClass = $(this).attr('class');
            var sBorrowValue = $(this).attr('value');
            var sBorrowName = $(this).attr('name');
            var sBorrowChecked = $(this).attr('checked');
            var checked = this.checked;

            if(checked){    
                alert("You are selecting too many");
                setsession(sBorrowValue, "SET");
            }
            else{
                setsession(sBorrowValue, "UNSET");
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the number of times a checkbox was checked using the `data` option.

In my example I incremented the counter **ONLY** for when the checkbox was checked (not when it was unchecked).

```js
$(document).on('change', '.set-counter', function() {
  // If the checkbox is not checked - return
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    return;
  }
  
  if ($(this).data('counter')) {
    $(this).data('counter', $(this).data('counter')+1)
  } else {
    $(this).data('counter', 1)
  }
  
  if($(this).data('counter') == 3) {
    alert('Checked too many times')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="v1" class="set-counter" />
```

Comment: Thanks Dekel, i will try it out in a moment

Comment: Im trying to work it out. I want to ask something. You change the code `delegate` to `on`. Does it matters?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method